# Redirect to another control DNN

Tags: redirect, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module, dotnetnuke-7

In my Page_Load event of my custom DNN module I retrieve the settings that I have stored using the following.

```
 if (((string)Settings["username"] != null) && ((string)Settings["username"] != ""))
  username = "";
 {
   username = (string)Settings["username"];
if (((string)Settings["password"] != null) && ((string)Settings["password"] != ""))
{
  password = (string)Settings["password"];
}
if (((string)Settings["baseServiceUrl"] != null) && ((string)Settings["baseServiceUrl"] != ""))
{
  baseServiceUrl = (string)Settings["baseServiceUrl"];
}
baseServiceUrl = "";
```

Now my question is how do I redirect it to my module settings(called settings.ascx) control if username, password or baseServiceurl is null.

I'm sure it's not as simple as Response.Redirect('settings.ascx');

my aim is to replace 
    username = "";

with a snippet similar to Response.Redirect('settings.ascx');

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks again Chris, your answer is correct but I decided to get the settings of the module via the modal pop up.   This is what I did to get the answer  to get the javascript popup script and url i right clicked on the gear icon using google chrome an inspected the element.

I then copied the contents the anchor tag href attribute, this looked a bit like

```
href="javascript:dnnModal.show('http://localhost/TestPage/ctl/Module/ModuleId/417?ReturnURL=/TestPage&popUp=true',/*showReturn*/false,550,950,true,'')">
```

In my default.aspx page I created an anchor tag without the href.  I made it a server control by putting runat=server and adding an ID to it and made the visibility false (in my logic i make it visible if it does not meet my criteria)

```
<a runat="server" class="btn btn-success" id="settingsLink" visible="false" > <img src="/images/action_settings.gif"><span>Settings</span></a>
```

Next I create a method to dynamically build my link

```
private string settingsUrlBuilder()
{
    var s = new StringBuilder();
    var urlPartArray = TabController.CurrentPage.FullUrl.ToString().Split('/');
    var partUrl = urlPartArray[3].ToString();
    s.Append("javascript:dnnModal.show('");
    s.Append(TabController.CurrentPage.FullUrl.ToString().ToLower());
    s.Append("/ctl/Module/ModuleId/" + ModuleId.ToString());
    s.Append("?ReturnURL=/");
    s.Append(partUrl);
    s.Append("&popUp=true");
    s.Append("',/*showReturn*/false,550,950,true,'')");
    return s.ToString();
}
```

This is where i use the function in the page load

```
settingsLink.HRef = settingsUrlBuilder();  settingsLink.Visible = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to load a different ASCX file that is registered in DNN (registered in the Module Definition, via the MANIFEST file) you do so by calling either the EditUrl method, or the NavigateURL Method in DNN.

EditUrl("Settings") where Settings is the ControlKey defined in the Module definition.

Edit URL is available off of PortalModuleBase, assuming your controls inherit from PMB.